# hydration error: Scroll colorChange in nextjs and tailwind

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, tailwind-css

Here's my root layout

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AiOutlineMenu, AiOutlineClose } from "react-icons/ai";

const Navbar = () => {
    const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);
    const [color, setColor] = useState("transparent");
    const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState("white");

    const handleNav = () => {
        setNav(!nav);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const changeColor = () => {
            if (window.scrollY >= 90) {
                setColor("#ffffff");
                setTextColor("#000000");
            } else {
                setColor("transparent");
                setTextColor("#ffffff");
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener("scroll", changeColor);
    }, []);
```

It changes fine on scroll but I keep getting errors:

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

someone help me out.